# WPF MediaElement white color is shown as gray

Tags: wpf, video, mediaelement

I try to show a MP4-Video using the MediaElement in WPF. Playing the video works just fine. However, the **white colors are displayed grayish**. When I open the video file in some other video player, the white color is shown as it should. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Play"
              Source="Resources/Videos/TestVideo.mp4" />
```

Video played as WPF MediaElement:
[image]

Same video played in Windows Media Player:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a background color set to gray in the element that contains MediaElement? Maybe that the background is transparent.

Comment: Yes, I see the same in other software that supposedly uses the same MediaElement component. But note that it's not just "white colors [that] are displayed grayish" - the entire image is "grayish". It's just that the whiter areas are far more noticeable. For example, compare the red arrow from both images. In the bottom image this is 255,65,24 (RGB). But in the top (gray) image this is 243,72,37 (RGB) - slightly darker. @GianlucaConte

Answer (score 5):

Changing the dynamic range to "Full (0-255)" in NVIDIA Settings solved this issue.

[image: NVIDIA Settings - Adjust video colour settings]